# compiling snippets of clojure(script) into javascript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Where in the clojurescript library can I access a function to compile snippets of clojure into js?

I need this to run in the **clojure** (not clojurescript) repl:

```
(->js '(fn [x y] (+ x y)))
=> "function(x,y){return x+y}"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Snippet compilation from Clojure REPL

```
(require '[cljs.analyzer.api :refer [analyze empty-env]])
(require '[cljs.compiler.api :refer [emit]])

(let [ast (analyze (empty-env) '(defn plus [a b] (+ a b)))]
  (emit ast))

;; result
"cljs.user.plus = (function cljs$user$plus(a,b){\nreturn (a + b);\n});\n"
```

### Snippet compilation from ClojureScript REPL:

```
(require '[cljs.js :refer [empty-state compile-str]])

(compile-str (empty-state) "(defn add [x y] (+ x y))" #(println (:value %)))

;; Output (manually formatted for easier reading)
cljs.user.add = (function cljs$user$add(x,y){
  return (x + y);
});
```

[`compile-str`](https://github.com/cljsinfo/cljs-api-docs/blob/catalog/refs/cljs.js/compile-str.md) takes a callback as the last argument. It will be called with a map either with a key `:value` containing result JS as a string or `:error` with the compilation error.

In both cases `org.clojure/tools.reader` is needed on your classpath.

Comment: oh awesome! thanks so much. I saw that function but didn't know about empty state. how would you define a specific namespace (instead of `cljs$user`)

Comment: oh hang on... my bad... I'm after the same function but for the clojure repl. slightly edited the question

Comment: @zcaudate I have updated the answer with compilation from Clojure REPL

Comment: why is it that `(analyze env '(fn [a b] (+ a b)))` returns `""`?

Comment: I guess [the comment from the code](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/16666f37cc13ead5a66330046db82a2976b6f1f0/src/main/clojure/cljs/compiler.cljc#L763) explains it clearly :): "fn statements get erased, serve no purpose and can pollute scope if named". When they are not inside a statement they are a no-op and can be ignored.

Comment: that's good to know. I have to look for an alternative then =/

Answer (score 2):

there is a lightweight alternative: https://github.com/kriyative/clojurejs which creates the right output asked by the question.

Examples can be seen here: https://github.com/kriyative/clojurejs/wiki/Examples