# Compile ClojureScript in Java application

Tags: clojurescript

I'm trying to compile `String` that contains Clojure Script code in Java/Groovy. I'm not really happy with using `"java -jar ...".execute()`.

Is there any way to invoke clojurescript library (version 1.8.51) to compile code?

Edit:
So combining these two links I got this code (Groovy):

```
    IFn require = Clojure.var("clojure.core", "require");
    require.invoke(Clojure.read("cljs.analyzer.api"))
    require.invoke(Clojure.read("cljs.compiler.api"))

    IFn emptyEnv = Clojure.var("cljs.analyzer.api", "empty-env")
    IFn analyze = Clojure.var("cljs.analyzer.api", "analyze")
    IFn emit = Clojure.var("cljs.compiler", "emit-str")

    final inputText = "(defn plus [a b] (+ a b))"
    emit.invoke(
            analyze.invoke(emptyEnv.invoke(), "'$inputText"
            )
    )
```

My problem is that emit function return empty string :/. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Edit2: The analyze method return this:

```
{
    :op :constant, 
    :env {:ns {:name cljs.user}, 
    :context :statement, 
    :locals {}, 
    :fn-scope [], 
    :js-globals ...removed..., 
    :form #object[org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl 0x37816ea6 "'(defn plus [a b] (+ a b))"], 
    :tag any
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be very easy to call ClojureScript Compiler API from Clojure, for example [as presented in answers to a similar question on how to do it from Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36300173/compiling-snippets-of-clojurescript-into-javascript).

But as you want to do it from Java or Groovy, you will have to use some [Clojure Java API for calling Clojure from Java](http://clojure.org/reference/java_interop#_calling_clojure_from_java).

Comment: I think you should post it as another question as it sounds as a new problem you are now solving. The issue in your code is that you are passing a String to `analyze.invoke` whereas it should be a Clojure datastructure representing the code. So instead of passing the plain string, pass the result of call to `Clojure.read(inputText)`.

Comment: I've added Clojure.read and removed quote - everything works. Thanks!